# java card Applet RSA encryption problems with Android

Tags: android, nfc, javacard, apdu

I am new to java card development. I have used nxp jcop 31-36 java card and nexus s for testing the application. I want to encrypt data coming from the android app using RSA1024 and send back to the android application.

1. RSA1024 and RSA2048 algorithms can't work with the nexus s Application. I can't receive any encrypted data from the card. When I test the application with eclipse jcop shell tool it works properly.
2. when I run the application in nexus s it crashes. It gives some weird sound when I tap the java card to android phone. It may be the java card application crashed or the weird sound may be from the android OS level.
3. I tested the Application with Samsung S2. Sometimes it works but sometimes it crashes. In the S2 the encryption works fine (but we have to keep wile card 2 or 3 minutes).

These are the steps I followed to establish the connection on android phone:

- created the ISO dep connection
- selected the Application(00A40400AID)
- using transive method I send data to java card

In the Java card in the installation: I have created the RSA key pairs and get the RSA public key and private key. In some method i got the APDU buffer and read data and encrypt this data. Then those are send back to the card.

Is there any problem in Android Os or JCOP 31/36 card?

Each time I requested to java card, I need to reset the java card. How do I reset the Java card?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "RSA1024 and RSA2048 algorithms can't work with the nexus s Application"? And from "when i run the application in nexus s the application is crashed" if your app is crashing then there's a bug, but probably in your application, have a look at the stack trace in LogCat or post it up here.

Comment: AFAIR there no official API for accessing the smartcard on Android. How do you access it?

Comment: Thanks Peanut & Robert.Robert i uesd ISO 14443 standard for communicating.it means using  android isoDep i create communication.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html

Comment: There is no way we can answer this without more detail, e.g. code would be nice. Please try and localize the problem. Then create an SSCCE for it.

Comment: As a general remark, check that command and response lengths are no longer than [`getMaxTransceiveLength()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#getMaxTransceiveLength%28%29).

Comment: Thanks Nfc guy.Thanks your response.i already checked that one maximum length is 261 bytes. but i send only 256 bytes.i thought that may not be the problem because Samsung S2 works fine sometimes.so may be the reason is that java card need more power consumption.Do you know anything about the java card power consumption.

Comment: @YouKnowbetter that's impossible to answer as well without knowing the details of the card *and antenna*. NXP contactless cards are pretty resilient compared to most other cards, but I'm not sure about the power supplied by mobile devices. Note that RSA *does* use the most power as it is a long operation performed by the asymmetric coprocessor.